# Can I figure out the numberOfLines of NSString without creating UILabel?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I just want to know number of lines, given the font, constraints, and the text. Can I figure it out without creating a `UILabel`?

```
+ (int)numberOfLines:(NSDictionary *)data{
    NSString *myString = [some string calculation];
    CGSize sizeConstrain = CGSizeMake(some constrain calculation);
    CGSize stringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:someFont constrainedToSize:sizeConstrain];

    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0,
                                   0,
                                   stringSize.width,
                                   stringSize.height + 2);

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:labelFrame];

    label.text = myString;
    return label.numberOfLines;
}
```

Comment: I guess this is a very tedious job to find, as size, font and iPhone device screen resolution makes a lot of permutations and combinations.

Comment: What I do is just use a separate, never-displayed label -- adjust the attributes, add the text, and then read the dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**

```
+ (int)numberOfLines:(NSDictionary *)data{
        NSString *myString = [some string calculation];
        CGSize sizeConstrain = CGSizeMake(some constrain calculation);
        CGSize stringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:someFont constrainedToSize:sizeConstrain];


        return (stringSize.height/someFont.lineHeight);
    }
```

EDIT: I used this for UITextView and iOS7

```
 - (CGFloat) getRowsForText:(NSString*) text{

CGFloat fixedWidth = 300;

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrapStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragrapStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

textStepAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                font,NSFontAttributeName,
                paragrapStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                nil];

NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:textStepAttr];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];


return (rect.size.height / font.lineHeight) ;
}
```

Comment: `sizeWithFont` is deprecated in iOS7, use `sizeWithAttributes:` instead.